# GUI for git for creating multiple commits at once

Tags: gui, git

Currently I am using git gui for quickly creating commits and visualizing changes.

I have the bad habit (yes, I know) of not committing as frequently as I should, and usually end up with changes that belong to multiple commits.

Instead of scrolling through all changes, create one commit, scroll through all changes again and create another commit, I was wondering if there are any gui tools that would allow me to create multiple commits at once.

Ideally I would like to only scroll through all the changes I've made once, decide which commit each change should go to, decide the order of the commits I've created, and batch create all the commits in one go.

(I also welcome command-line solutions that could handle this nicely, if there exist one...)

I'm currently using Linux and would prefer a free solution (but would welcome anything that does the job, just for the sake of checking it out)

Comment: Does that include splitting changes done to a given file into multiple edits – or just picking complete files for each commit?

Comment: @Izzy yes it should ideally include splitting changes within a single file, just like git add --patch

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the proper search term would be to have multiple staging areas

Relevant question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473768/is-it-possible-to-stage-multiple-sets-of-changes-separately-in-git

Best I could find is a beta software: http://ben.villagechief.com/2012/01/multiple-git-staging-areas.html